# Vote timestamps have 00:00:00 time

Tags: feature-request, bug, data-explorer

On data explorer, why do votes have the time part of their `creationDate` (a `DATETIME` datatype, that is a date and a time) all set to midnight?

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168578) shows that this has been the case for some time.

It means that certain time sensitive queries can't be made.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Anonymity of voting.

Comment: Fine... I will post another question then. I think I have attracted a downvoting stalker. I'll collect the info the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voting has, and always will (should!) be anonymous.

Not only do they show support (through upvotes), but they could also show the opposite (through downvotes). As such, the possibility exist - however small - for one to link voting behaviour with community members and therefore attempt retribution for negative feedback... a very human quality. To nullify this risk of association, votes are considered anonymous by removing the timestamp.